# Xamarin.iOS deployment terminates for both Simulator and Device. Error MT1001: Could not find an application at the specified directory

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I have a solution with,

- Xamarin.iOS project
- NetStandard 2.0 project

The tools I use are,

- Visual Studio for Windows 2019 (v 16.3.2)
- Xamarin.iOS SDK (13.2.0.42)

I can successfully build the application. But it gives this error on launching for both the Device and the Simulator,

> error MT1001: Could not find an application at the specified directory: /Users/myUser/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs/builds/MyApp.iOS//bin/iPhoneSimulator/Debug/MyApp.app

When I checked the Xamarin.logs for more info, I see this,

> Xamarin.Messaging.Ssh.SshCommandRunner|Warning|0|Failed to execute 'which mono64': ExitStatus = 1

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify the Platform Target in a way to allow a **x64** build.

Right click on the *Xamarin.iOS* project and selection *Properties*. In the *Properties Window*, under *Build tab*, select either **Any CPU** or **x64** for the appropriate **Configuration** and **Platform**.

[image: Set Platform target]

That's all  Try to redeploy.